# Ruby: Working with Arrays & Loops - The Simple Moving Average

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops

working with simple moving averages in ruby, and came up with this code, specifically a three-day moving average:

```
 a = [3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 9, 7, 8, 9, 11]
 sma = []

 for i in 2 ... 9 do
   sma.push((a[i] + a[i-1] + a[i-2])/3.0)
 end
```

This code passes and it seems simple enough, however, what if the array contains over hundreds of items? How would I add 50 items for a 50-day average? Is there a different approach or should another loop be nested into the code?

*Also, I understand there are gems out there for this type of operation, but I'm more interested in creating this from scratch.

Comment: I'm pleased you found my answer helpful, but in future consider holding off awhile before invoking the green checkmark.  (I suggest at least a couple of hours.) Many newcomers to SO select the first answer posted that works for them. Unfortunately, that may discourage other, possibly better, answers, and also may short-circuit members who are still working on answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method [Enumerable#each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) is perfect for this calculation:

```
def moving_average(a, ndays, precision)
  a.each_cons(ndays).map { |e| e.reduce(&:+).fdiv(ndays).round(precision) }
end
```

```
a = [3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 9, 7, 8, 9, 11]

moving_average(a,3,2)
  #=> [2.67, 2.33, 2.67, 5.33, 7.0, 8.0, 8.0, 9.33]
```

For this example,

```
enum = a.each_cons(3) 
  #=> #<Enumerator: [3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 9, 7, 8, 9, 11]:each_cons(3)>
```

The values the enumerator `enum` passes into the block can be obtained by converting `enum` to an array:

```
enum.to_a 
  #=> [[3, 4, 1], [4, 1, 2], [1, 2, 5], [2, 5, 9],
  #    [5, 9, 7], [9, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9], [8, 9, 11]]
```

`map` then converts each of these elements to an average.

---

If `a` and `ndays` are large, greater efficiency can be achieved as follows.

```
def moving_average(a,ndays,precision)
  (0..a.size-ndays-1).each_with_object([a[0,ndays].sum]) do |i,arr|
    arr << arr.last - a[i] + a[i+ndays]
  end.map { |tot| tot.fdiv(ndays).round(precision) }
end

moving_average(a,3,2)
  #=> [2.67, 2.33, 2.67, 5.33, 7.0, 8.0, 8.0, 9.33]
```

After totaling

```
tot1 = [3, 4, 1].sum
  #=> 8
```

which is needed to compute the first 3-day moving average, the total of `[4, 1, 2]`, needed to compute the second 3-day moving average, is  calculated as follows:

```
tot2 = tot1 + 2 - 3
  #=> 7
```

where `2` is the last element of `[4, 1, 2]` and `3` is the first element of `[3, 4, 1]`.

While there was no time savings for this example it can be seen that computing each total from the previous one would save time when `a` and `ndays` are large, as the computational complexity is reduced from `O(n^2)` to `O(n)`, where `n = a.size`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked out. I was not aware of this method, another one to jot down!

Comment: Although this is a nice trick, note that it is NOT a valid moving average unless you shift the array `lookback-1` to the right. The SMA of `[3,3,3]` should not be `[3,3,3.6]` (as provided by the above code), but rather `[nil,nil,3]`

Comment: @DannyB, the code yields `moving_average([3,3,3],3,2) #=> [3.0] `. Note that for any array, `arr`, `arr.each_cons(n)` returns an enumerator that will generate `arr.size-n+1` arrays of size `n`. As the moving averages begin with the first `ndays` elements I see no reason for the `nil` placeholders.

Comment: If you see no reason for nil placeholders, I guess you did not try to plot these two on a chart. In almost all real world applications I have used, any rolling series you generate must be a parallel array to the source, so you can plot them together. Dont get me wrong, its a great answer, its fast and efficient, but in my case, it must be offset by `lookback-1`.